# Javascript Browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Can anyone please let me know what attributes I should use instead of these (which I have used for Internet Explorer) to work in chrome or firefox:

For changing visibility of an element:

```
obj.style.visibility = 'visible/hidden';
```

For getting the element:

```
document.getElementById("id");
```

For writing a string value into an element:

```
obj.innerHTML = "....";
```

To set or retrieve the left position of an object:

```
obj.style.posLeft/posTop = ...;
```

Or can anyone please suggest some article on browser compatibility?

Comment: "please suggest some article on browser compatibility" - Do you want the [red pill or the blue pill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill)?

Comment: Only the last need to be changed to: `obj.style.left/obj.style.top = '10px';` (must add px (or other unit) otherwise it won't work)

Comment: those statments work in *pretty much*, every browser, legacy or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj.style.posLeft/posTop` should be `obj.style.left/top`, and their value must always include a unit. Other than that, the snippets you showed should work on all browsers. Also, those positioning properties only work for elements that are not "statically" positioned, i.e., elements with `position: absolute`, `position: relative` or `position: fixed`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the rapid reply, have you any article to which you refer to? How did you know this?

Comment: I know by experience, I've been using JavaScript for over a decade. I don't have any specific article to recommend, but I often check the [MDN doc pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), which includes compatibility information for most functions. Another good reference is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com), where you can check the compatibility of many js functions, css properties and selectors, and html5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

All are supported. You can check supported browsers at w3c. For example for posLeft http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 1):

answers above are correct, but i'd like to add, that you'd better use any popular javascript framework to avoid things like:

```
window.screenY, window.screenX (for Firefox)
window.screenTop, window.screenLeft (for IE and Opera)
```

and other differences you will run into later

ps. http://caniuse.com/ is good too